# How to increase query speed without using full-text search?

Tags: sql, performance, optimization, postgresql

This is my simple query; By searching `selectnothing` I'm sure I'll have no hits.

```
SELECT nome_t FROM myTable WHERE nome_t ILIKE '%selectnothing%';
```

This is the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE`

```
Seq Scan on myTable  (cost=0.00..15259.04 rows=37 width=29) (actual time=2153.061..2153.061 rows=0 loops=1)
  Output: nome_t
  Filter: (nome_t ~~* '%selectnothing%'::text)
Total runtime: 2153.116 ms
```

`myTable` has around 350k rows and the table definition is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    nome_t text NOT NULL,
)
```

I have an index on nome_t as stated below:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_m_nome_t ON myTable
USING btree (nome_t);
```

*Although this is clearly a good candidate for Fulltext search I would like to rule that option out for now.*
This query is meant to be run from a web application and currently it's taking around 2 seconds which is obviously too much;
**Is there anything I can do, like using other index methods, to improve the speed of this query?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, ILIKE '%selectnothing%' always needs a full table scan, every index is useless. You need full text search, it's not that hard to implement.

---

Edit: You could use a Wildspeed, I forgot about this option. The indexes will be huge, but your performance will also be much better.

> Wildspeed extension provides GIN index
>   support for wildcard search for LIKE
>   operator.

http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/wiki/wildspeed

Comment: @Frank Heikens, Being hard or not it's not the point, could you please elaborate on why `'%selectnothing%'` always needs a full table scan although the field is indexed? Still, without using full text search, which would be the best alternative to achieve the same result?

Comment: the best you can possibly expect is a full index scan. but that is usually not a benefit if the table has only one column ;) Why? http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning

Comment: @Markus Winand, I did knew about prefixing with the wildcard but searching `'selectnothing%'` takes the same amount of time as does `'selectnothing'`... Maybe I'm missing something obvious here...

Comment: Check Wildspeed to give LIKE a performance boost. Ordinary btree indexes are sorted, LIKE '%var%' doesn't know where to start for a search, it has to check everything: sequential scan will be the best option.

Comment: @Frank Heikens, Thank you, that's useful info! :)

Comment: @andre matos, well LIKE without prefix wildcard should be able to use an ordinary b-tree index on that column. If you post your complete sample, i might be able to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @Markus Winand, What other info do you need?

Comment: You can emulate ILIKE by creating an index `on (lower(nome_t))` and then searching `WHERE lower(nome_t) like 'foo%'`

Comment: @andre matos, right--everything there. sorry. you are probably falling into the "C" locale trap. Have you tried `CREATE INDEX ... (nome_t text_pattern_ops)` ? (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/indexes-opclass.html)

Answer (score 1):

another thing you can do-- is break this nome_t column in table myTable into it's own table.  Searching one column out of a table is slow (if there are fifty other wide columns) because the other data effectively slows down the scan against that column (because there are less records per page/extent).